# Is there any way to force requestAlwaysAuthorization to always show a dialog?

Tags: ios, core-location

Is their anyway to force `requestAlwaysAuthorization` to always show a dialog ? because if the user previously decline the authorization then `requestAlwaysAuthorization` do nothing.

The problem i face is that i can redirect the user to the app settings when i detect `kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied` via `openUrl UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString` **BUT** is the `requestAlwaysAuthorization` was never called then it's will redirect to something a little buggy named "settings for null"

Comment: Unfortunately you can't. It is suppressed by iOS.

Comment: yes but it's a little crazy, user is in the settings of the app, click of "use my current position" but nothing to do to warn him to enable also location services settings in his phone :(

Comment: If it was already asked once, it will not show again. What you can do to work around is to have a modal that pops once you detect something different from `authorized` you explain the user and shows a button to redirect him to the settings

Comment: thanks gijow, but the modal will be useless (or the redirect will be useless) if kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied because of location services deactivated GLOBALLY :( in this case we must call  requestAlwaysAuthorization (only if it's was never called before)